# React Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child.

`labelList` is an array of objects. I have added some sample data below. I am trying to map over these objects so that I can generate separate row of each object data. I tried doing multiple things such as `Object.keys(labelItem).map` ... but that the error is still not resolved.

```
<tbody>
  {
    this.state.labelList.map((labelItem,index)=>{
      return (
        <tr key={ index }>
          <td>{labelItem.label}</td>
        </tr>
        )
    })
  }
</tbody>
```

Data:

```
labelList: [
  {
    "label": "Title",
    "translation": "Titre"
  },
  {
    "label": "First Name",
    "translation": "Prenom"
  },
  {
    "label": "Last Name",
    "translation": "Nom"
  },
  {
    "label": "Marital Status",
    "translation": "Etat civil"
  },
  {
    "label": "SSN",
    "translation": ""
  },
  {
    "label": "Birth Date",
    "translation": "Date De Naissance"
  }
]
```

Comment: where does this error point to and have you imported Field from redux-form or its a custom component

Comment: Nope. I haven't used redux-form. The field is a component that does styling and passes props to input fields.

Comment: What does `{ ...this.inputManager("index") }` return, I feel you wanted to pass index and hence also should have used `{ ...this.inputManager(index) }`

Comment: @AmitJS94 Usually this error means that you have imported an Object somewhere in your JSX.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That string index means it can be used as this.state.index Both the values shouldn't be same i will change that and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, as seen from the JS fiddle below. Inspect the value of `this.state.labelList` first, it might not be what you think.

```js
var labelList = [
  {
    "label": "Title",
    "translation": "Titre"
  },
  {
    "label": "First Name",
    "translation": "Prenom"
  },
  {
    "label": "Last Name",
    "translation": "Nom"
  },
  {
    "label": "Marital Status",
    "translation": "Etat civil"
  },
  {
    "label": "SSN",
    "translation": ""
  },
  {
    "label": "Birth Date",
    "translation": "Date De Naissance"
  }
]

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <tbody>
        {
          labelList.map((labelItem,index)=>{
            return (
              <tr key={ index }>
                <td>{labelItem.label}</td>
              </tr>
              )
          })
        }
      </tbody>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, the labelList was incorrect. Even flow was giving that error. Thanks for the help.